# How to test the convergence of $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\sin{x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

How to test the convergence of $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\sin{x}dx$?

As we know $\sin{x}\ge-1$ and $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}-1dx=\int^{0}_{-\infty}-1dx+\int^{\infty}_{0}-1dx=-\infty-\infty$. Does that mean  $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\sin{x}dx$ diverges?

Comment: This integral indeed is divergent, however, as a side note, if you replace the $x$ with $x^2$, the integral is convergent (!!)

Comment: No, for this same argument would imply $\int_{-\infty}^\infty 0 dx$ diverges, and it doesn't. To see that it diverges you should notice that $\lim_{a \to -\infty} \int_a^b \sin(x) dx$ and $\lim_{b \to +\infty} \int_a^b \sin(x) dx$ both do not exist. This is easy to do because you have an explicit antiderivative.

Comment: Indeed, agreed with Ian, the conclusion that the integral is divergent, but the OP's reasoning behind it, is shady...

Comment: Just principle value exists

Answer (score 3):

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(x) dx$ diverges, but not for the reason you gave. Recall that in order for the integral to converge, both
$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x) dx$
and
$\int_{-\infty}^{0}\sin(x) dx$
must converge. We will show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x) dx$ diverges.

The improper integral is defined as
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x) dx = \lim_{c \to \infty}\int_{0}^{c}\sin(x) dx$$
Now
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{c}\sin(x) dx
&= 1 - \cos(c)
\end{aligned}$$
The right hand side does not have a limit as $c \to \infty$ (it oscillates between $0$ and $2$), so $\int_0^{\infty}\sin(x) dx$ diverges, as claimed.

Comment: Yes, very true +1